# Why did the Council suffer a loss of power?

Tags: chilling-adventures-of-sabrina

At the beginning of the show, the members of the Council informed "Faustus Blackwood" that they had suffered a loss of magical "potency." Later, the characters attribute this to the Dark Lord withdrawing his gifts from the Church of Night in revenge for Sabrina and company having imprisoned him.

However, the Council are the ones who choose the Anti-Pope. They're not members of the Church of Night. We know that Lucifer didn't withdraw his powers from all witches, because the hedge witches still have their powers, as does Faustus Blackwood after being separated.

So why were the Council experiencing the same symptoms?